# flutter: how to use old google-services.json in new flutter application

Tags: react-native, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

A few years ago I created an application with **react-native**. In this app, I used the firebase cloud message. Now I recreate this application with **Flutter**. Both applications have the same **ApplicationId**.

Now I am trying to use `google-services.json` that I created for  **react-native** in the Flutter application. After using `google-services.json` in my flutter project, when I send a message from my firebase console, the flutter app doesn't do any action! Mean not received a message from the console!

Is it possible to use the old `google-services.json` in the new Flutter app with the same **ApplicationId**?

Comment: Your google-services.json should be under the android/app folder.

Comment: Is here. to test i create google-services.json from other console and it is works.`/android/app
$ ls
build.gradle  google-services.json  src
`

Comment: An interesting situation!

Comment: Yes, And i am confused, What's going on !!!@Akif

Comment: download it from your firebase console, add it under `your-project/android/app/` if it exists you must initialize firebase app before using any api in flutter